# Looking for resource management system for manpower and devices

Tags: resource-management, human-resources

We have a testing lab.
I looking for software that can Mange the lab resources (manpower, testing devices, car, lab room, ...)
that help me to manage the booking for a test like to see 
who are free and available to do the test on what date and time
What device is available for that test on the same date and time
what room are free for the test on the same date and time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web app [teamdeck.io](https://teamdeck.io/features/resource-scheduling/)

- it allows adding bookings to people and resources
- it allows defining the availability of employees and other resources.
  You can find free resources filtering the calendar by chosen availability.
- you can add extra information to each person or resource to group them at the 
  calendar view.

Comment: Welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! Please note that when you're promoting your own product, you have to be explicit about it; see the [Help Center](/help/promotion).